# owl-carousel with animation on multiple item

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel, animate.css

I have owl-carousel with multiple items
I would like to have a small bounce on right when the slide position change.

```
<div id="owl-production" class="owl-carousel owl-theme ">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_1.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_2.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_3.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_4.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_5.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_6.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_7.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://image_8.jpg" class="animate__animated animate__bounceInRight"></div>
</div>
```

My js for the carousel:

```
jQuery('#owl-production').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    dots:false,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:5000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    },      
})
```

And now I remove classes "animate__animated animate__bounceInRight" just before images to be active

```
var myCarousel = jQuery('#owl-production');
myCarousel.on('change.owl.carousel', function(event) { // before slides are active
    jQuery('.owl-item').find('img').remove('animate__animated animate__bounceInRight');
});
```

And i add my animate.css classes when images is active

```
myCarousel.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) { //when slides are actives
    jQuery('.owl-item').find('img').addClass('animate__animated animate__bounceInRight');
});
```